# tee hangs in bash -- is there an alternative syntax?

Tags: bash, daemon, tee

Let's say you have a series of scripts that you don't own and, therefore, can't modify, that may spawn background processes without redirecting stdout and stderr.  I've noticed that in bash, tee'ing the output, as shown in the following example, does not return when the script is done if the background process is still running (and has open file descriptors for stdout or stderr).

```
./runme.sh 2>&1| tee runme.out
```

Where `runme.sh` is defined as:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start a fake daemon
perl -e 'while(1) { sleep(1) }' &
printf "Enter your name: "
read name
echo "Goodbye $name"
```

How can I run scripts like this in bash while capturing all output and get back to the prompt when the script is done?

Answer (score 4):

alternative syntax could be to use process substitution

```
./runme.sh > >(tee runme.out) 2>&1
```

this way `tee` is no more a child process of current shell and shell will wait only for `runme.sh` termination whereas in a pipeline it's waiting for all process termination.

Note that `tee` and subprocesses are still running after `runme.sh` terminates.

Answer (score 0):

> does not return when the script is done if the background process is still running (and has open file descriptors for stdout or stderr)

So don't do that. Daemon tools will generally redirect stdout/err for this reason, and you can do it manually too:

```
perl -e 'while(1) { sleep(1) }' < /dev/null  > mydaemon.log 2>&1 &
```

Now that it's not keeping the pipe open, you can `tee` robustly without hacks.